# Share a cropped video as an output to the extended screen

Tags: video, video-editor, video-recording

I have Qt code where I developed a GUI to show the output from data acquisition from a camera, I would like to show the cropped output on the extended screen of size 640*480. Is there any software that can automate the procedure by selecting a rectangular cropped window that is output to the second screen .